# How to iterate TR > img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through the TR:Img and find if that TR has class but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

HTML:

```
<tr id="ItemDetail:0:parent"> 
    <td>
        <a id="itemDetail:0:linkShowHide" 
            name="itemDetail:0:linkShowHide" 
                href="javascript:toggleRow('itemDetail:0')">
            <img class="showDetail" id="itemDetail:0:Img" src="/s.gif"></a>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

Jquery:

```
$("[id*='parent']':Img'").each(function(){
   var x = $(this);
   if(x.hasClass("showDetail"))
   {
      alert('gotit');
   }
})
```

Comment: why down vote for ... care to explain?

Comment: @JordanHendrix: yes i have tried with lowercase, still getting the error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

Comment: quotes around `:Img` , and it's not a valid pseudo selector

Comment: @PranavCBalan: I have tried something like this `$("[id*='parent:img']").each(function(){` i'm not getting error now but its not looping... I think i'm not using the correct selector?

Comment: try `$("[id*='parent'] img")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

You get this because the selector is not valid..

Change this selector syntax

`$("[id*='parent']':Img'")`

To

`$("[id*='parent'] img")`

Note the space between the `id` selector and `img`.. Space is used between selectors to specify parent child relationship ( for any level deep).

The above selector means ... Find the `img` element which is inside any level of a parenrt element who's `id` contains parent.

Thanks to **Matt Browne** who pointed this in comments below.

Also if your intention is to only get the `img` tag which has `showDetail` then add that as well in the selector. And you can eliminate the If check inside..

`$("[id*='parent'] img.showDetail")`

This will give you only the `img` tag that has the specified class ..

Hope this helps.

Comment: @NickKahn, you could also change it to `$("[id*='parent'] img.showDetail")` rather than using an if statement and `hasClass()`.

Comment: I thought of it But then it also put me in thought that he might use a else as well . But not shown it here... Anyways I'll put that point in answer as well